# error in process sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid number

Tags: emacs, clojure, dependencies, lisp, read-eval-print-loop

I've looked at all of the similar questions on stack overflow. This one is different enough to warrant a separate question. Basically, I can't start a repl server because I get the error below. It's been pointed out that this is typically a dependency issue, but I'm updated, to my knowledge. What am I getting wrong here? Here's the full error:

```
error in process sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid number: 0.8.3
 at clojure.lang.LispReader.readNumber (LispReader.java:352)
    clojure.lang.LispReader.read (LispReader.java:278)
    clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList (LispReader.java:1398)
    clojure.lang.LispReader$VectorReader.invoke (LispReader.java:1347)
    clojure.lang.LispReader.read (LispReader.java:285)
    clojure.lang.LispReader.read (LispReader.java:216)
    clojure.lang.LispReader.read (LispReader.java:205)
    clojure.lang.RT.readString (RT.java:1878)
    clojure.lang.RT.readString (RT.java:1873)
    clojure.core$read_string.invokeStatic (core.clj:3815)
    clojure.core$read_string.invoke (core.clj:3805)
    clojure.core$mapv$fn__8445.invoke (core.clj:6912)
    clojure.core.protocols$fn__8159.invokeStatic (protocols.clj:168)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn (protocols.clj:124)
    clojure.core.protocols$fn__8114$G__8109__8123.invoke (protocols.clj:19)
    clojure.core.protocols$seq_reduce.invokeStatic (protocols.clj:31)
    clojure.core.protocols$fn__8146.invokeStatic (protocols.clj:75)
    clojure.core.protocols/fn (protocols.clj:75)
    clojure.core.protocols$fn__8088$G__8083__8101.invoke (protocols.clj:13)
    clojure.core$reduce.invokeStatic (core.clj:6828)
    clojure.core$mapv.invokeStatic (core.clj:6903)
    clojure.core$mapv.invoke (core.clj:6903)
    leiningen.update_in$parse_args.invokeStatic (update_in.clj:13)
    leiningen.update_in$parse_args.invoke (update_in.clj:9)
    leiningen.update_in$update_in.invokeStatic (update_in.clj:36)
    leiningen.update_in$update_in.doInvoke (update_in.clj:24)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:146)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:705)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:667)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:660)
    leiningen.core.main$partial_task$fn__7331.doInvoke (main.clj:284)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:139)
    clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke (AFunction.java:31)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:667)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:660)
    leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invokeStatic (main.clj:334)
    leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke (main.clj:320)
    leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invokeStatic (main.clj:343)
    leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke (main.clj:336)
    leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__7420.invoke (main.clj:453)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.invokeStatic (main.clj:442)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke (main.clj:439)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:705)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:665)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic (main.clj:514)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invoke (main.clj:510)
    clojure.main$main.invokeStatic (main.clj:664)
    clojure.main$main.doInvoke (main.clj:616)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:705)
    clojure.main.main (main.java:40)
```

EDIT:

So I've gotten farther on this problem and I think I'm down to the last little issue or two. The file that is being pulled that causes the java.lang.NumberFormatException is cider.el which you can finder in your emacs.emacs.d\elpa\cider-[VERSION NUMBER, in my case 20210104.915]. You open your cider.el file and on line 392/393, in this version, you'll find:

(cider-add-to-alist 'cider-jack-in-dependencies
"nrepl/nrepl" "0.8.3")

So changing this line, recompiling it, and reloading emacs gets the number throwing the java.lang.NumberFormatException to change to whatever I changed it to (recompile by using byte-compile-file, hitting enter, then passing it the address of the document). Adding another set of double quotes gets a null value error of sorts (obviously) and doing any type of backslashing for exceptions and sort doesn't seem to solve the issue. So, since the few related posts (though with much less detail) seem to hint at changing the version number, I'm going to have to assume that I have to do that. What version number would work best here?

TEMP SOLUTION SO FAR:

start a repl with "lein repl" in command line and connect to it manually using the connect command "cider-connect" and specifying the localhost (I started the repl in same directory as project and it detected it easily). This is not good enough for me as a permanent solution but gets me up and going temporarily until a better solution is found.

PERMANENT SOLUTION:

see below

Comment: Looks like you wrote `0.8.3` where a string (like `"0.8.3"`) is needed?

Comment: It would have likely been auto-generated by leiningen or something like that, where would I find 0.8.3 to change it?

Comment: project.clj or ~/.lein/profiles.clj -- if maybe in the emacs config (i dont use emacs, so i dont know about the setup); if in doubt grep for the number in your project first.

Comment: So I can upvote it, can you put your solution as an answer.

Comment: Aaron Bell, you're too kind. I've done as you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your dependencies. I had an issue where my java jdk was basically broken (java's fault, not mine, in so far as the code is concerned). I ended up using the latest OpenJDK (number 15). That worked. If you get lots of java specific type errors and those errors change with the versions that you're using, then consider updating your java jdk. I was using LTE versions before and the latest fixed it.

Comment: That didn't work for me.  I had to add the dependency and plugin to my `profiles.clj` and then disable the "Cider Inject Dependencies At Jack In" setting in Emacs.  This way, it executed a simple "lein" command without trying to inject the dependencies, but took them from my profile.