# Clojure REPL in DOOM emacs didn't show up

Tags: emacs, clojure

I'm stuck here. I've just installed emacs & doom for Clojure. I opened the project, core.clj, and I can't see the repl running. I've tried using `SPC m`, but it only shows as in the screenshot

[image: Clojure REPL didn't show up in DOOM emacs]

Thanks a lot for the help. I'm still newbie here

Answer (score 0):

Answered here [65566706](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65566706/error-in-process-sentinel-could-not-start-nrepl-server-java-lang-numberformate)

1. start git cmd
2. type `lein repl` it'll start repl in git cmd
3. Go to doom emacs type `[SPC m c]` a shortcut for `cider-connect-clj`
4. choose local host
5. type port local host as shown in step 2